# Error when attempting to run kotlin in Vscode

Tags: java, android, powershell, kotlin, visual-studio-code

The following error shows in the terminal when I attempt to run a simple `kotlin` code vscode using the code runner extension. I have installed the kotlin compiler and set the bin folder to path. I have also done the same with the java sdk.

Error:

```
PS C:\Users\Judah> cd "c:\Users\Judah\Desktop\Dev\Kotlin\" ; if ($?) { kotlinc
fun main.kt -include-runtime -d fun main.jar } ; if ($?) { java -jar fun main.jar }

'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.

error: source file or directory not found: fun
error: source file or directory not found: main.kt
error: source file or directory not found: main.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

You make Code Runner run in Terminal, and normally the path shown after `PS` in terminal is **current working directory**, and the `.kt` file should be executed like

```
kotlinc hello.kt -include-runtime -d hello.jar
java -jar hello.jar
```

[image]

If `fun` mentioned in the error is the extra module you add for building and compiling, please post some detailed information like your folder structure and code to clarify your question.

If not, check if there's `"code-runner.executorMap"` in your **settings.json** and  delete it. Reload window then try again.

Answer (score -1):

Bro there is a space in between your code file remove that and all fine,
I was facing the same problem thank me later

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).